# Javascript RegExp to change a line depending on the content

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm really having trouble with Javascript and regular expression. We've a log file generated with log4J and would like to render into an html page. The idea is to add some styles to the lines depending on the type of error (Warning, info..).

It's possible to create a regular expression that transform each line :

```
 [                          main] [ WARN] (26-01-12 17:06:09.168) Engine started
 [         startup-schema-loader] [ INFO] (26-01-12 17:06:09.168) Load on Startup Schemas Setup
 [         startup-schema-loader] [DEBUG] (26-01-12 17:06:09.168) dispatching request   [GwtReloadAllSchemasServerRequest : ]
 [               engine-thread-2] [ INFO] (26-01-12 17:06:09.171) Re-loading all schemas
```

into something like :

```
<span class="log-warn">[                          main] [ WARN] (26-01-12 17:06:09.168) Engine started</span>
<span class="log-info">[         startup-schema-loader] [ INFO] (26-01-12 17:06:09.168) L</span>
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go, just store the logs inside a var called logs.

```
var html = logs.replace(/.*/g,function($0){
    var r = $0.match(/[A-Z]+(?=])/g); 
    return r ? '<span class="log-'+ r[0].toLowerCase()+'">' + $0 + '</span>' : $0})
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/nFwQT/

---

Explanation: In the first line we "split" every line using regex and apply a function to each one, in the second line we use a regex that match an upper-case word followed by a "]", in the third line we return a SPAN tag with a class based on the matched word or just the element if no match was found.

Comment: Textbook answer... I like it.